# When I post params , Postman not get response, loading forever

Tags: laravel, postman, guzzle

Here my Controller

```
  $http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client; $response = $http->post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/token', [
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'password',
                'client_id' => 2,
                'client_secret' => 'vZ2wi8dOIJLueXRzP4Dqvraad0V1GBj3DDy8RaXj,
                'username' => $request->username,
                'password' => $request->password,
            ]
        ]);
  return $response->getBody();
```

When I post params like below
[image]

Not get the response.
Please help me

Comment: try to return $response->getBody()->getContents()

Comment: Hi @iCoders still not working bro

Comment: try to dd() response

Comment: nothing happend bro @iCoders still loading